# Using $ne Mongo operator on subdocuments in Meteor still returns the full collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've create a test database like this:

```
Test.insert({_id: "XJAGgP3whnNd2HZec"}) ;
Test.insert({_id: "user1"} );
Test.insert({_id: "user8"} );
Test.insert({_id: "user5"}) ;

Test.update({_id: "XJAGgP3whnNd2HZec"}, {
$push: { users:{name8: "test5"}} });
Test.update({_id: "user5"}, {
$push: { users:{name8: "test5"}} });
Test.update({_id: "user8"}, {
$push: { users:{name9: "test5"}} });
Test.update({_id: "user1"}, {
$push: { users:{name9: "test4"}} }) ;
```

From meteor mongo I can search for results. For example:

```
> db.test.find({'users.name9': "test4"}).count()
1
> db.test.find({'users.name9': {$ne: "test4"}}).count()
3
>
```

If I put the same query inside Meteor. For example:

```
console.log(Test.find({'users.name9': { $ne: "test4" } }) ),
```

Meteor returns a collection object with all the entries.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I'm running 0.6.5.1, I did exactly as you've outlined here(copy and paste) and it works fine for me. Here's a repo of what I did. https://github.com/davidworkman9/Meteor--ne-test

Comment: In the end I raised a ticket which has since been closed. I think my logic in the above comment wasn't quite right. Clearer in this ticket: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the logic in my original question wasn't quite right.

I raised a ticket which has now been fixed:

Clearer in this ticket: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1451

Answer (score -1):

I just tried that too, and it works fine for me. I don't know what your problem is, but I'd try `meteor reset` (which refreshes your database deleting everything and starting over), and if that doesn't work, I'd try creating a new project. You can copy your code files over to the new project, if you don't want to write them again.

Comment: In the end I raised a ticket which has since been closed. I think my logic in the above comment wasn't quite right. Clearer in this ticket: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1451